# Formatting integer in SSRS with leading zeros

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I would like to format as 10 digits in total regardless of the length of actual data, filling with leading zeros.
Example actual data is `123456`, Then my result would be `0000123456`. But the actual data has the dynamic length, means we can't guess all the time.
Can I achieve in SSRS? Instead of formatting in SQL?

Answer (score 7):

In the report, set fields formating to as many zeros as the digits you  want to appear.
For example for 10 digits the format code should be "0000000000"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Doing a dynamic padding of leading zeroes can be obtained in multiple ways. Either you can directly do in the database itself then display the same in RS or get the raw data from DB and then do the padding in RS. For your reference I have shown both the ways.

Sample data to be used in RS -

```
declare @t table(i varchar(10))
insert into @t values (1),(12),(123),(1234),(12345),(123456),(1234567),(12345678),(123456789),(1234567890)
select i,RIGHT('0000000000'+ISNULL(i,''),10) 'ipadded' from @t
```

Expression used in RS for padding -

```
=Right("0000000000" & Fields!i.Value.ToString, 10)
```

Images -

[image: Output]
[image: Expression in RS]
[image: Sample data]

Comment: How about if the fields has to show the aggregate like `=First(Fields!...Value,"dataset")` ?

Comment: I don't find this requirement in the original question, suggestion - accept the answer which suits your requirement and then start afresh with a new question.